# Check textfield before Segue

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to complete Segue by checking text fields wether they are empty and if they are it should print a error message, but when i'm trying i get this error message:

control reached end of non-void function

What is the problem, i've found this method in the apple documentation

My code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([HomeTeam.text length] != 0 && [HomePlayers.text length] != 0 && [AwayPlayers.text length] != 0 && [AwayTeam.text length] != 0) {
        NSString *errorMessage = @"You did not fill in all the fields";
        errorLabel.text = errorMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: The method is supposed to return a BOOL. It's not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value from this method. For example:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([HomeTeam.text length] != 0 && [HomePlayers.text length] != 0 && [AwayPlayers.text length] != 0 && [AwayTeam.text length] != 0) {
        NSString *errorMessage = @"You did not fill in all the fields";
        errorLabel.text = errorMessage;
        return NO; // need a user input: don't perform the segue
    }

    return YES; // check successful; perform segue
}
```

Comment: No idea :) It could be an unrelated issue. Posting a stack trace might be helpful.